# How do I integrate Crashlytics with Android Instant Apps?

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, android-instant-apps

Does [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) work with [Google Play Instant](http://g.co/InstantApps) and if so, how do you setup your project correctly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, Crashlytics does work with Android Instant Apps, in fact it is the recommended crash reporting solution at this stage as it has been tested and works fine.

For setup:

#### Step 1

Open the `build.gradle` file in your base feature module and follow the steps on the [public docs site](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) to configure Crashlytics as normal.

#### Step 2

At the top level of your base feature module `build.gradle` file, add the following Crashlytics flag:

```
...
android {
    ...
}
crashlytics { instantAppSupport true }
...
```

#### Step 3 (optional but recommended)

Add the Instant App library dependency in your base library project `build.gradle` if not already there as per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/reference.html):

```
compile 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
```

**Note:** to use this dependency you will need to add the newer `maven.google.com` repository to your gradle files if you haven't already (see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library) for details).

Then in your code, after setting up Crashlytics, set a boolean value to log if the current run is an Instant App:

```
Crashlytics.setBool("InstantApp", InstantApps.isInstantApp(context));
```

#### Update as of Aug 2017 - New issue that breaks support

A recent tools update seems to have caused a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65804378) when using Crashlytics and Instant Apps that logs the following error:

> This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at
>   https://fabric.io/sign_up, install an Android build tool and ask a
>   team member to invite you to this app's organization.

Until the issue is fixed, please try this as a workaround: after building, find the file `com_crashlytics_build_id.xml`, open it up, copy the `<string>` from there that contains your Fabric key and paste it into your normal `strings.xml` file for your feature module. Then re-build and run.

#### Update as of Nov 15, 2017 - Issue fixed

The issue above is now fixed as of Fabric gradle plugin v1.24.5. As your gradle file should have:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
```

You shouldn't need to do anything but sync up your build to pull down the updated plugin with fix.

Comment: To use compile 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.0.0'
Don't forget to add: maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } to the repositories

Comment: Thanks @LorenzoValentijn, i added a note in the answer.

Comment: After following all this steps my Instant app crashes on start with 
`This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up, install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.` error

Comment: It seems there is a bug in recent versions of Instant Apps / Studio that is stripping out the generated Crashlytics key from the generated APKs. Until that's fixed, try this as a workaround. After building, find the file "com_crashlytics_build_id.xml", open it up, copy the <string /> from there and paste it into your strings.xml file for your feature module. Re-build and run.

Comment: The String copy works (at least no compilation error), but whenever clean the project, it always complaints duplicate resources :(

Comment: FYI, issue should be fixed now, I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: I have configures crashlytics in InstantApp. I can not see crashes in fabrics console. I tried copying string file from "com_crashlytics_build_id.xml". It is telling dublicate resource. I deleted build folder/clean/rebuild. Not working...:(

Comment: I think this is not supported anymore, after moving to Firebase: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1944#issuecomment-963297681

Answer (score 2):

Besides what the accepted answer says, I also needed to add the next lines at the build.gradle file of the application (apk) module to get it running.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested with 1.24.5 and it was fine.

> I was able to setup my project like this:

1. in base module: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install
2. [How do I integrate Crashlytics with Android Instant Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361850/how-do-i-integrate-crashlytics-with-android-instant-apps/44361851#44361851)

   - add to base/build.gradle:

     - crashlytics { instantAppSupport true }
     - compile 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'   (*1.0.0 also works)
   - additionally add to the base module Application class:

     - Crashlytics.setBool("InstantApp", InstantApps.isInstantApp(context));

**My test instant app built, I triggered a crash, and my dashboard logged it.**

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65804378) they will re-open to examine.