# Crashlytics Answers throwing error with Android instant apps

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, android-instant-apps, crashlytics-android

I am using Crashlytics version 2.6.8 for my Android app. I have configured Crashlytics in base feature following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44361851/790124). Crashlystics is initialized with Fabric using following code snippet

```
Fabric.with(context, crashlyticsKit);
```

Crashlytics Answers throws this exception on startup of Android instant apps

```
E/Answers: Failed to enable events
java.io.IOException: ftruncate failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(RandomAccessFile.java:630)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.QueueFile.initialize(QueueFile.java:213)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.QueueFile.<init>(QueueFile.java:130)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.events.QueueFileEventStorage.<init>(QueueFileEventStorage.java:58)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.events.GZIPQueueFileEventStorage.<init>(GZIPQueueFileEventStorage.java:32)
    at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersFilesManagerProvider.getAnalyticsFilesManager(AnswersFilesManagerProvider.java:44)
    at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler$4.run(AnswersEventsHandler.java:121)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: ftruncate failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at libcore.io.Posix.ftruncate(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.ftruncate(BlockGuardOs.java:148)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.setLength(RandomAccessFile.java:628)
```

Is it caused due to storage access? If so, Is it possible to configure Crashlytics from accessing storage in case of Instant apps?

Comment: Have you set up the dependency for Answers? https://fabric.io/kits/android/answers/install
`compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13@aar') { transitive = true; }`

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem like you are initializing Answers itself, only Crashlytics?

Try something like this if you want Crashlytics and Answers from Fabric:

```
    final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Crashlytics(), new Answers())
            .debuggable(true)
            .build();
    Fabric.with(fabric);
```